# Mysterious C++ threading crash

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, pthreads

The following code strangely crashes when entering the `run` function. None of the printfs trigger, and single-stepping into the function will cause a crash. Is it undefined behaviour, or a compiler bug? I'm on MacOS compiling with Apple clang 12.0.0. It crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct Chunk {
    // the array must be this big
    // other array sizes don't trigger the bug consistently
    uint8_t array[524288];
};

std::thread generator_thread;
std::mutex generator_lock;
std::vector<Chunk*> to_generate;
std::condition_variable data_ready;
std::atomic<bool> running;

void begin();
void run();

void begin() {
    running = true;
    auto func = [] {
        run();
    };
    generator_thread = std::thread(func);
}

void run() {
    printf("Running in generator\n");
    while (running) {
        printf("Running in loop\n");
        Chunk *task;

        // take a chunk from the queue
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(generator_lock);
            data_ready.wait(lock, [] { return to_generate.size() > 0 || !running; });
            if (!running) break;

            task = to_generate.back();
            to_generate.pop_back();
        }

        printf("deref chunk\n");

        // Despite never being executed in this example, this line merely existing
        // will cause a crash when entering the run_generator function.
        Chunk chunk = *task;

        // *task.chunk;
        // ^^^ Only having the line above will not trigger the bug; it must be assigned
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    begin();
    while (true) {
        printf("run\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "This function used to work, and was completely untouched, but now suddenly no longer works." Could be memory corruption. Try using a program like Valgrind. Also check for possible race conditions and other undefined behavior in your thread.

Comment: @LHLaurini I ran with the thread sanitizer and address sanitizer, no memory corruption. I may try valgrind and update back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when you change your function to pre-reserve a stack frame with space for a half-megabyte object ... it crashes right at the start of the function when setting up that stack frame?

That's probably because you made `sizeof Chunk` equal to the entire default OSX thread stack size of 512Kb. If you single-step into the function, you should be able to see the *instruction* that triggers the fault, and it will likely be part of the stack frame setup/function preamble.

All of this is implementation-specific (the stack frames, the per-thread stack size), but putting really big things on the stack is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I forgot about this. I was so focused on making the threading work that I guess I had tunnel vision.